# Flash CS5 not exporting SWC?

Tags: flash

So for some weird reason i've run into a bug today.  I'm trying to export a FLA in CS5 to SWC but click the "export to SWC" setting in the publish settings.  my problem is for whatever reason it's not exporting the swc file.  I've never had this issue before, is there a fix to this issue?

Comment: try to be more specific, and tell what output you get from flash, is it shows any error messages, is it at least compile the code into swf

Comment: It's only outputting the SWF and there are no compiler errors when it's publishing that.  It's simply not exporting the swc even with the option checked.

Answer (score 13):

This usually happens if there is no ActionScript to export. Even if there is some vector art or some symbols, there needs to be some ActionScript elements. Flash will never output an empty SWC; instead, it just outputs nothing.

Make sure you have "Export for ActionScript" and "Export on 1st frame" checked for at least one symbol in the library, or have some code on your timeline.

Comment: I have checked these two options on one symbol, but still output nothing.

Answer (score 1):

One main reason is because you have errors in the code and in compiling it will screw up the SWC.  Check for duplicate indentifiers and also duplicate functions.  The errors are not reported once the SWC fails.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem out of the blue, and discovered the issue was a conflict with another swc in the same directory. If I deleted the other swc or moved the problem fla elsewhere, it would create the swc as expected.

I never tracked down the exact source of the conflict and couldn't find any error messages coming from CS5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my problem was that I have a MovieClip named "dragBtn" and I have used the same name to export it as a as3 class. So I removed the export as3 class and worked again. This is indeed very annoying, because at least we should get an error message but we don't.